# Trying to use logical or operator in Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, eval

So I am showing the visibility depending on the status ID. I have two scenarios to check for, if the program expired, or if the program in unavailable. I got it to work to show for program expired, however I am having problem doing the OR. I have to check the status id with status ID !=Expired OR Unavailable. My code for expired is as follows

```
  Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Status_Id").ToString()) !=(int) Testing.dal.Enums.ProgramStatus.EXPIRED %>'>
```

I have something like Testing.dal.Enums.ProgramStatus.Unavailable that I need to check for as well.

Comment: Really you should be doing this logic in the code behind, rather than in the markup.  The markup should just be binding the already computed boolean value.  You're mixing your UI and your business logic.  On top of that, the data binding context doesn't give you as effective of tools as the code behind for performing this operation easily and effectively.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually need a conjunction (`AND`).

```
Visible='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Status_Id").ToString())
             !=(int) Testing.dal.Enums.ProgramStatus.EXPIRED
             &&
             Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Status_Id").ToString())
             !=(int) Testing.dal.Enums.ProgramStatus.Unavailable %>'>
```